# Don't I have to malloc() this array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm struggling to learn the C rules of malloc() / free().  Consider the below code, which runs just fine.  (On Linux, compiled with GCC.)  Specifically, I'm wondering about the `arr` array.  I get that you have to malloc for all the struct elements *within* the array... ***but why don't you have to malloc for the array*** ***itself***?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define ARR_SIZE 100

typedef struct containerStruct{
    int data1;
    int data2;
    int data3;
    // ...etc...
} container;

int main(){

    container* arr[ARR_SIZE];       // Don't I have to malloc this?

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++){
            arr[i] = (container*) malloc (sizeof(container));   // I get why I have to malloc() here
    }

    ...do stuff...

    for(i=0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++){
            free(arr[i]);        // I get why I have to free() here
    }

    // Don't I have to free(arr) ?
    return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing that the `container* arr[ARR_SIZE];` line tells the compiler all it needs to know to carve out the space in memory for the array, which is why this code works.

But it still doesn't "feel" right, somehow.  When I malloc() something, I'm reserving memory space on the heap, right?  But my `container* arr[ARR_SIZE];` call creates the array on the stack.  So... the array of container* porters exists on the stack, and all of those container* pointers point to a container struct on the heap.  Is that correct?

Comment: For a real surprise, try `container arr[ARR_SIZE];` without the star, and see that you don't have to use `malloc` at all to get an array.

Comment: You are declaring an arry of pointers, in a way that does not require `malloc()`. You ***might*** have to `malloc()` what they point to; or you might not, depending on how/whether you dclare that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ARR_SIZE` is fixed member of the dynamic array `*arr[ARR_SIZE]`, you no longer have to allocate memory for the whole array, but just the elements within it, as they are flexible in this case.

When you [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) any sort of dynamic array, it is safe to always check the return value of the `void*` pointer returned from `malloc`. Additionally, when you [`free`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) each element, it is even safer to set each member to `NULL` again, to prevent the pointer from accessing memory again.

Illustrated through this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    int data1;
    int data2;
    int data3;
    // ...etc...
} container_t;

int
main(void) {
    container_t *arr[ARR_SIZE];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(container_t));
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Malloc Problem here\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        if (arr[i]) {
            free(arr[i]);
            arr[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two lines, with `arr[i]= malloc( sizeof( container ); if ( NULL == arr[i])...` works just fine, doesn't need 4 levels of parenthesis, and is thus *much, much* less bug-prone.  Stuffing an assignment into a conditional clause saves a line for a textbook at the cost of being much harder to maintain and much more likely to have bugs.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Cheers. I modified it.

Answer (score 4):

Right beneath your declaration of `arr`, you have the following:

```
int i;
```

Which reserves enough space *(probably on the "stack")* to store an `int`. Does this "feel" wrong to you as well?

The declaration of `arr` is no different. The compiler allocates enough space *(probably on the "stack")* for a `ARR_SIZE` element array of `container *`s.

Comment: Worth noting that such thing as *stack* is a compiler-implementation detail which is not dictated by the C language standard.

Answer (score 4):

You can choose either one of the following options:

---

```
int i;
container** arr = malloc(sizeof(container*)*ARR_SIZE);
for (i=0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(container));
// do stuff...
for(i=0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++)
    free(arr[i]);
free(arr);
```

---

```
int i;
container* arr[ARR_SIZE];
for (i=0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(container));
// do stuff...
for(i=0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
```

---

```
container arr[ARR_SIZE];
// do stuff...
```

---

Since `ARR_SIZE` is constant, you may as well choose the last option.

Answer (score 4):

> When I malloc() something, I'm reserving memory space on the heap, right?

Don't say that, the heap is an implementation detail. You're *dynamically allocating memory*. You're also responsible for dynamically freeing it again.

> But my container* arr[ARR_SIZE]; call

It's not a call, it's a declaration.

> creates the array on the stack.

Don't say that either, the stack is also an implementation detail.

You're declaring a local (here an array of pointers) with automatic scope, and the compiler is responsible for managing its memory and lifetime.

Its lifetime isn't dynamic, because it becomes unreachable as soon as you reach the `}` at the end of the enclosing block, and so the compiler can handle it for you deterministically.

All local variables behave the same here:

```
{
  int i;
  double d[2];
} /* neither i nor d are reachable after here,
     so the compiler takes care of releasing any storage */
```

> So... the array of container* pointers exists on the stack,

Consider the simpler declaration `container c;`. This is a local with automatic scope, and the compiler takes care of (de)allocation as discussed.

Now consider `container *p;`. This is *also* a local variable with automatic scope, but the variable is a pointer. You still need to point it *at* something manually, and if the thing you point it at was returned from `malloc`, you'll need to `free` it yourself.

Further consider a simple array `container a[2];`. Now you have a local *array* with automatic scope, containing two instances of your `container` type. Both instances have the same lifetime, it's still managed by the compiler. You can access `a[0]` and `a[1]` and pretty much anything else is illegal.

> and all of those container* pointers point to a container struct on the heap. Is that correct?

No. Finally consider `container* ap[2]`. Again we have a local array with automatic scope, containing two *pointers*. The type of the pointer is *pointer-to-container*, and the lifetime of the *pointers* is managed by the compiler. However, the pointers don't *point* at anything yet, and it'll be your responsibility to decide what to point them at, and figure out what lifetime that *pointed-at* thing has.

Once you do

```
ap[i] = malloc(sizeof(*ap[i]));
```

(you don't need to cast, and it's generally safer to avoid naming the type explicitly, in case you change it later and allocate the wrong size), you've allocated an object which you're responsible for freeing. You've also pointed one of the pointers in your array at this object, but that doesn't somehow change the lifetime of the pointer itself. The array just goes out of scope like usual *wherever* its pointers point.

Answer (score 2):

`container* arr[ARR_SIZE];` tells the *compiler* to allocate an array of `ARR_SIZE` **elements of type** `container*` and compiler allocates the memory accordingly.

In other words, this is similar to saying `int x[5] = 0;` where compiler allocates enough space for an array of 5 `int`s. In your case, compiler allocates enough space for `ARR_SIZE` number of pointers, `container*` and that is it. Now, it's upto you to make those pointers *point to* valid memory location. For that, you can either

- use memory allocator functions (which allocates memory from *heap*, as you mentioned)
- assign the address of other variables of the same type (does not need allocation from heap, anyway).

So, the bottom line, you don't need to allocate any memory *for* the array. For each individual array elements, you need to allocate memory using memory allocator functions as you want each elements to point to *valid* memory.

Comment: @SeanBright In general, that's correct, but not very relevant to _this_ case, right?

Comment: OP is asking why he doesn't have to allocate the array with malloc. I think it's perfectly relevant. (I deleted my previous comment because I noticed he already mentioned stack/heap in his question)

Comment: @SeanBright I still fail to see why that is relevant. an operation like `arr[i] = &arr2[i];` would take the heap out of context completely, right?

Comment: Then I guess we agree to disagree.